# HTML: Text above image and align center

Tags: html, css

Hi i am new in html and css. Right now i am design some text above and center the image. Also, if the image is too long, it automatically enter.
Thank you guys. Here my html image and text:

```
<div class="imgcontainer">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="image.jpg" id="imageid" alt="" />
        <span class="desc" id="text">
            Centered Rollover Text
        </span>
    </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This style should center image an text:

```
.imgcontainer { text-align:center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

use span tag above img tag and add this css for span :

```
span{ display:block; width:100%; text-align:center}
```